# Run ipynb from other file, but also update outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am currently using `import-ipynb` library, It works great, however, the one downside is that it leaves the file which you run untouched. What I would like to happen for the file to update its outputs when it is run, just like it does when you just press the "run all" button. Any solution is fine, I just need it to work. I thought maybe running some script using `os.system`. If you have any ideas, please let me know.